# Extract multiple substring matching pattern into columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My pandas dataframe has string like this

```
A=1;B=3;C=c6
A=2;C=c7;D=8
```

I want to extract the value in each field into separate columns, and then use the field name as columns like this

```
A    B    C    D
1    3    c6   NaN
2    NaN  c7   8
```

I tried split `df.str.split('=|;', expand=True)` but it splits both the value and field as separated columns

I also tried using `df.str.extract(r'=\s*([^\.]*)\s*\;', expand=True)` but it only return the first occurrence of the values.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here is possible use split in list comprehension - first by `;` and then by `=` and convert it to dictionary, so last is possible use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (df)
            col
0  A=1;B=3;C=c6
1  A=2;C=c7;D=8

L = [dict([y.split('=') for y in x.split(';')]) for x in df['col']]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
   A    B   C    D
0  1    3  c6  NaN
1  2  NaN  c7    8
```

**Detail**:

```
print (L)
[{'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': 'c6'}, {'A': '2', 'C': 'c7', 'D': '8'}]
```

Comment: I don't think it gets any simpler than using black magic.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is the regex way...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\w+)', x)) for x in df['col'])
```